# How to change color of single segment in segmented control

Tags: xcode, swift, background-color, uisegmentedcontrol, segment

I've created a segmented control for my app that consists of 4 segments. I know how to change a background color for the all four of them but I want each segment to have their own color:

1st segment - blue background color

2nd segment - red background color

etc.

Is there any way to achieve it in swift?

Comment: try to call this method func setBackgroundImage(_ backgroundImage: UIImage?,
               forState state: UIControlState,
             barMetrics barMetrics: UIBarMetrics)    and each segment having lable change that background

Comment: @Ramkumarchintala I'm pretty new to swift (started learning about two weeks ago) can you go into specifics please?

Comment: @Arsnii nibble try below mentioned way. otherwise take a toolBar With BarButton Iteams. look like a segment Control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try below code

```
func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
color.setFill()
UIRectFill(rect)
let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return image
}
```

> Use below metod for each segment set image (above method give image with color)

```
setImage(image: UIImage?, forSegmentAtIndex segment: Int) // can only have image or title, not both. must be 0..#segments - 1 (or ignored). default is nil
```